# Conditioning launchd scheduled job on file existence?

Tags: launchd

We have a scheduled job that we want to run on both our macOS and Linux hosts.

On Linux, with systemd we can just use this:

```
ConditionPathExists=/etc/this_file_must_exist
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/skip_if_this_exists
```

and the job will only execute if the first file exists, and the second file is absent (so we can pause the scheduled job from running, e.g. if we're testing a new version).

Is there an equivalent on macOS? I've seen others achieve a similar result by using Bash and just running `[[ -f /etc/this_file_must_exist ]] && run_my_job`` but this seems... not to be the ideal way.

`launchd.plist`'s manpage (https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/launchd.plist/ -- official link seems down) has `KeepAlive` but that's for keeping the service up, not preventing it from starting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Nope.

launchd can start jobs at scheduled times (with the `StartCalendarInterval` key), when particular files are modified (`WatchPaths`), or when files appear in a particular directory (`QueueDirectories`), but it doesn't have a way to test existence of a specific file, nor to combine conditions the way you want to.

So... something like a `bash` wrapper is what you're looking at. You can either write a bash script and run that with a `StartCalendarInterval` trigger, or use the `ProgramArguments` array to embed a miniature script directly in the plist:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>[[ -e /etc/this_file_must_exist ]] && [[ ! -e /etc/skip_if_this_exists ]] && exec /path/to/my_job</string>
</array>
```

Note: I'd recommend running your job from bash with `exec`; that makes the job replace the shell (rather than running as a subprocess), so launchd can monitor and manage it more directly.

Comment: That's good to know!

Comment: Thanks! A bit unfortunate launchd is no longer open source, so we can't even easily suggest an enhancement supporting this.